# Read and put INBOUND_MAIL through SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I tried to get the INBOUND_MAIL and put it in S3 then call a custom Lambda function in AWS. But it's not working. Here is what I have done.

- Verified my domain and my email address in SES
- Created and a rule set to read mail and put it in s3 bucket
- created group policy in s3 [GiveSESPermissionToWriteEmail]

Still it's not working. I'm receiving lot mails but none of them in s3 bucket. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the few days recharge I finally figured out the problem.
I did everything correct but I didn't put MX record for Amazon endpoint. Even after the MX record I didn't got emails because I already have another MX record in my DNS Server. So removed previous one. now it's working perfectly.